# jQuery.ajax error function never called after net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on Cordova

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I have an app with Cordova 4.3 installed. When I try to access using `jQuery.ajax` a site that's not working at that moment (due to a failure, maintenance mode, whatever), the app throws an error I can't catch (because it's in an async task) and any further execution of JS stops working as it should. I noticed that this error was arised by calling a non existing subdomain, and it popped a `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

The issue here is that the jQuery error method never gets called.

The code is ridiculously standard:

```
$.ajax({
  url: dummy_path + script_name,
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(course) {
    // it works, when success
  },
  error: function() {
    // never called
  }
});
```

I've already tried passing the `timeout` and `statusCode` parameters with proper values, calling `complete` and trying to `.abort()`. No luck!

Comment: As per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): *error [...] This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests*. Do you get any other handler like `success` or `complete`?

Comment: `success` gets perfectly called, I'm not sure about `complete` on success, but surely it doesn't get called when there's an error. Anyway, looks like I can't just use `error`, right?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yeah, it definitely was the cross domain issue. I knew about JSONP, but not error functions as well. If you wrote the comment as an answer, I'd accept it!

Comment: Well, my comment explains why it doesn't work but it doesn't provide a solution or workaround, or even proper reference that explains it cannot be done—so it isn't an actual solution.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Well, I'm fan of people that's sincere and say something's not possible in the scene the poster is showing. Sure, there can be solutions, but probably not for _a Cordova 4.3 app trying to contact another server using ajax and where the error function is not working_, because it's pretty much just that, without using a custom native plugin, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure a timeout in your $.ajax config object, so add something like:

```
timeout: 10000
```

If left unset, this will run as long as the browser will let it.  In Cordova's case that may well be indefinitely.  Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Sadly I already tried this, as well as setting functions split by `statusCode`, but it seems that cordova is reluctant to use any kind of cancelling/erroring system. Sorry because I used a bad wording, it's not that the app gets blocked because the query never leaves, but because after that error is thrown (on an async task, no way I can catch it), the JS execution gets compromised and doesn't work again.